# Background service in Android cannot resolve/access outlook.office365.com, unless phone is in charge?

Tags: android, outlook, android-volley, okhttp

I've been really struggling with a strange problem. I have a simple code that authenticates with office365 through REST API's and reads calendar entries for the day.
The code works perfectly when my app is running in the foreground. I get all the calendar events, generate my notifications and all is good.
When I put the app in the background (The app actually is a background service hooked into Android AlarmManager - AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP and runs repeatedly), the notifications stop coming. When I plug in the debug cable to look at Logcat, all of a sudden, even though my app is in the background still, the notifications start coming. As soon as I remove the cable, they stop. When I looked at the debug logs from when the phone was not plugged in, this is what I see. I have used Volley for networking and before that I used okhttp3. Here are logs from both:

Volley:

```
03-28 16:47:56.822 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:47:56.822 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:03.899 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:03.900 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:08.930 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:08.931 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:13.959 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:13.959 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:18.989 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:18.990 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:24.028 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:24.034 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:29.068 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:29.070 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:34.100 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:34.100 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:39.115 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-28 16:48:39.116 27031-27685/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

okhttp3:

```
03-28 12:40:08.114 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
03-28 12:40:08.115 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
03-28 12:40:08.115 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:33    4)
03-28 12:40:08.115 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.    java:196)
03-28 12:40:08.116 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
03-28 12:40:08.116 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
03-28 12:40:08.116 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
03-28 12:40:08.116 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:69)
03-28 12:40:08.116 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
03-28 12:40:08.116 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
03-28 12:40:08.116 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-28 12:40:08.117 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at     okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at     okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err: at     okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err: at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
03-28 12:40:08.118 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err: at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
03-28 12:40:08.119 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
03-28 12:40:08.120 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
03-28 12:40:08.120 10329-20079/com.microsoft.samples.outlookquickstart     W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I'm not sure what is the problem and how I can fix it.

Any ideas on what the issue is? Has someone run into this before? I am using Samsung Galaxy A5 2017. It is not any different on other brands of phones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For others who may have the same issue:

After some struggle I found the answer.
The answer is the power saver was on and the cryptic messages mean that the background networking feature is disabled by the power saver.
As soon as I turned off the power saver, all of the notifications started coming regularly with no issues. To test, I then turned it off and notifications stopped with the same error.